# How to read XML file using System.IO.Stream with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

I will be passing the xml file like this:

```
File1.PostedFile.InputStream 

//reading xml file.....
public static void readXMLOutput(Stream stream)
{

    System.Xml.Linq.XDocument xml = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(stream);

    var query = from p in xml.Element("ste").Element("Application")
                //where (int)p.Element("Id") == 1
                select Page;

    foreach (var record in query)
    {
        Response.Write("dfe") + record.Element("dfe").Value;
    }
```

error:

> Error  1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(string)' has some invalid arguments
>
> cannot convert from 'System.IO.Stream' to 'string'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you using .NET 3.5 by any chance? `XDocument.Load(Stream)` apparently only arrived in .NET 4.

You might want to use [the overload which takes an `XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356384.aspx) (which is supported in 3.5).

EDIT: Sample code:

```
static XDocument LoadFromStream(Stream stream)
{
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
    {
        return XDocument.Load(reader);    
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i am using 3.5 framework. what should be the alternative to it?

Comment: can you please show me some sample lines Stream using xmlReader?

Comment: @teki: Edited to give a method you could use.

Answer (score 3):

The `XDocument.Load(Stream)` method is new in .NET 4. For earlier versions of the framework, you need to read the stream first and pass it in as a string:

```
public static void readXMLOutput(Stream stream){
    string streamContents;
    using(var sr = new StreamReader(stream)){
        streamContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    var document = XDocument.Parse(streamContents);
}
```

Comment: i am gettign error when it try to load the streamContents and teh error is: "Illegal characters in path.", my xml is pretty much very simple not special characters nothing.

Comment: XDocument.Load takes a filename, not the XML itself. You *could* use XDocument.Parse instead - but the code in this answer currently assumes UTF-8... it would be more robust to use XmlReader.Create IMO.