# How to load an XML file from a file in the solution, build with Embedded Resource?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

Here's an outline of my solution:

[image]

I've set the build to Embedded Resource and when I generate the application the XML file doesn't appear in the /Release folder. This is correct, I want this behavior.

Now I'm trying to load that file into an XDocument so I can parse the data within:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parsing XML.");

        XDocument championXml = XDocument.Load("Champions.xml");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

And I get a file not found error because it's trying to find the xml file in the full path of the release folder.

How can I properly load this data into my XDocument?

Comment: You need to load the resource, not the file in your project.

Comment: @jrummell: My project doesn't have any resource file. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Related and good answear. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file/3314213#3314213

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GetManifestResourceStream()`:

```
var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using(var stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("Namespace.Champions.xml"))
{
    // ...
}
```

The exact names used to reference resources can be found by calling `GetManifestResourceNames()`.

Comment: I'm using .NET 3.5, and it seems the `XDocument.Load(stream)` is only available for .NET 4 and up. I can't use it in my application. How do I use this stream and turn it into xml? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838349%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: Found my answer in another question. Thanks! Will mark this as answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281714/how-to-read-xml-file-using-system-io-stream-with-linq

Answer (score 6):

Reference the resource property directly and use Parse instead of load:

```
XDocument championXml = XDocument.Parse(Properties.Resources.ChampionsXML);
                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                           //Name of your resource |
```

The namespace will be somewhat different depending on your project structure.

Answer (score 1):

You should get stream from assembly:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(name)
```

Where name will be something like: 'LinqToXml.Champions.xml'